# Install packages requiring C/C++/Fortran with CRAN/Check_rhub

Tags: r, data.table, devtools, cran

I am repeatedly running into an error when checking my new R package with `devtools::check_rhub()`. I get the same error with CRANs automatic tests. I can install these packages no bother locally.

My package uses plotly, for which data.table is a dependancy

The error message I get when **Installing package dependencies** is:

> Packages which are only available in source form, and may need
> compilation of C/C++/Fortran: 'utf8' 'data.table' These will not be
> installed

Then later on when:

> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading there is no package called 'data.table' Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]],
> c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : Calls: ...
> loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
>
> Execution halted

This uses Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, R-devel, 32/64 bit

So the package will not load. How do I make it compile on the RHub and CRAN?

Comment: I don't think SO is proper place for such question. Try reaching out rhub support. `data.table` windows binaries are not available for R-devel yet, so it installs from sources. Why it is failing to do so I have no idea.

Comment: I agree although johnm's solution works great so will leave here for others to find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar issues recently.
This resolved it, using the rhub package  :

```r
  rhub::check(
  platform="windows-x86_64-devel",
  env_vars=c(R_COMPILE_AND_INSTALL_PACKAGES = "always")
)
```

I think you should be able to pass that `env_vars` argument to `devtools::check_rhub()` function as well.